# CheckBox setChecked has no effect

Tags: android, checkbox

I've read all the answers to this question on here and nothing has helped yet.

```
public class ServerConfigFragment extends Fragment {

  private CheckBox checkBox_HDMI = null;
  private Handler updateScreen;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  updateScreen = new Handler();

  checkBox_HDMI = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_Server_Conf_HDMI);

  checkBox_HDMI.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            m_commsController.sendCmd(VideoStreamSettings.sendHdmiCommand(isChecked));
        }
    });

  final boolean hdmi = getHdmiSettingFromServer();

  updateScreen.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {  
              checkBox_HDMI.setSelected(hdmi);
            }
          });
  }
}
```

So upon my app's initial launch it querys the server's hdmi status and I want to set my checkbox to match that. I can see from the log I'm getting the correct value but so far I haven't been able to get my checkbox to check on/off programmatically.
I've tried with and without a `Handler`, hardcoding `true` and `false` into `setChecked()`, and placing the code in `onResume`. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a mistake that you're calling `setSelected(hdmi)` instead of `setChecked()`?

Comment: use `checkBox_HDMI.setChecked(hdmi);`

Comment: Yep, code-blind + copy and paste error, thanks guys!

Comment: Also I might add that in plain ol Java it seems `setSelected` is equivalent to `setChecked` in Android even though it means something very different for us.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a check box and want to programmatically check the check box

Use this

```
checkBox_HDMI.setChecked(hdmi);
```

Instead of

```
checkBox_HDMI.setSelected(hdmi);
```